# PHP indicate main image

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an image uploader where users can select 'main image' or 'primary image'. After they select one, it's name will be stored in a hidden input. When they click on the upload button, the main image should set 'is_mainimage = 1' in the database, and the rest should be 'is_mainimage = 0'. My problem is that I can't set it to 1. I've tried different ways but I only got these results:

1. All images' is_mainimage set to 1.
2. All images' is_mainimage set to 0.
3. Always the first uploaded image's is_mainimage set to 1.

This is how my database looks like:

```
id | productid | thumbnailimage | is_mainimage
1  |     12    |     1.jpg      |    0
2  |     12    |     2.jpg      |    1
```

And this is my code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
    $file = $filesTempName[$i];
    $is_mainimage = 0;
    if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
        if($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] == $_POST['mainimage']){
            $is_mainimage[$i] = 1;
        } else {
            $is_mainimage[$i] = 0;
        }
        $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($file, $data);

        $statement->bind_param("sii", $data, $productid, $is_mainimage);
        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

The hidden input is `$_POST['mainimage']`

Comment: remove the `[$i]`

Comment: Then always the first uploaded image gets is_mainimage 1. Not the one from $_POST['mainimage']

Comment: My bad. The problem wasn't with this part of code. But you were right, [$i] isn't needed here. Thanks.